# passing instance variable to a setter

Tags: python-3.x, properties, getter-setter

I'm trying to pass an instance variable to a method which returns a property (setter and getter), and I can't seem to do so. I want the method which returns a property in a separate class so that I can use inheritance and add additional checks as desired. Please see the code below:

```
class CheckProperty():
    def prop_check(self,name,maximum):
        private_name = '_'+name
        
        @property
        def prop(self2):
            return getattr(self2,private_name)

        @prop.setter
        def prop(self2,x):
            if ( x > maximum ):
                print('In CheckProperty: Trying to set number to a value > maximum')
                x = maximum
            setattr(self2,private_name,x)

        return prop
                
class TestSetter():
    
    def __init__(self,maximum):
        self.maximum = maximum
        self._number1 = 0
        self._number2 = 0
        self._number3 = 0
        
        self.number1  = 10
        self.number2  = 10
        
    # CASE 1
    # creating setters manually works, I can create a getter and setter for the
    # variable/property number which checks against self.maximum
    # so, self.maximum gets passed (somehow) to the setter
    
    @property
    def number1(self):
        return self._number1

    @number1.setter
    def number1(self,x):
        self._number = x
        if ( x > self.maximum ):
            print('Simple setter/getter: Trying to set number to a value > self.maximum')
            self._number = self.maximum

    # CASE 2
    # this works as expectd. I can't set the value of number1 to greater than 3
    number2 = CheckProperty().prop_check('number2',3)

    # CASE 3
    # the following, however, does not work. Python says: name 'self' is not defined
    # which makes sense, but begs the question: how does self get passed to the
    # property (descriptor) in CASE 1
    
    # number3 = CheckProperty().prop_check('number3',self.maximum)
```

This code can be invoked with:

```
    # first import the classes by using something like
    # from <module> import TestSetter
    tt = TestSetter(3)
    tt.number1 = 5
    tt.number2 = 10
```

Answer (score 4):

### I'd like to know why 'Case 3' does not work, and if there is a way of getting 'Case 3' to work

The `self` is meant to refer to a class instance. You use `self` where it is not defined, right out in the class where no specific object is yet known.

There is no way to make the **Case 3** working, also declaring a static variable in the class. the `__init__` method isn't run until `TestSetter` is instantiated. `number3 = ..` is run whenever the class definition is encountered in the code, so the value of the static variable will not be the one passed as argument in the `__init__`.

---

### How is self passed to the `check_prop` in the three case?

#### Case 1

The `property()` return a special [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties)

When you write:

```py
@property
    def number1(self):
        return self._number1
```

You are creating an object of class property by passing the function `number1` as the first parameter to its constructor. Remember that functions in python can be passed around like any other object, because they are also objects.

It is equal to:

```py
def number1(self):
    return self._number1
number1 = property(number1)
```

#### Case 2

Instances of `self` get passed to functions (and also to methods, and even operators) all the time. Just calling `CheckProperty().prop_check('number2',3)` the self is implict passed to `prop_check`.

### Case 3

This case use the same logic as the **Case 2** so you expect that `self` is automatically passed to the `prop_check`, and it do, exactly as the **Case 2**, but the problem is that you are trying to access `self.maximum` and pass it as parameter. In the class is not defined yet.

---

### Note

- In the **Case 1** the maximum value is `3` as you expect because the above explaination, so the value that you set in `TestSetter(3)` call is taken.
- In the **Case 2** the maximum value is 3 because you declared `number2` as `number2 = CheckProperty().prop_check('number3',3)`. That means that if you change the value of `TestSetter(3)` call to another value, `3` is always taken.
- In the **Case 3** the `self` is not recognized but the logic is the same as the **Case 2**, if you replace the `self.maximum` with a number it works exactly as the **Case 2**.

Comment: "The self is meant to refer to a class instance. You use self where it is not defined, right out in the class where no specific object is yet known."  

This is my problem. Why is self defined in Case 1 but not in Case 3?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that there is no way to get Case 3 to work. I can put my checks inside code like Case 1 but it just leads to ugly programming.

Comment: Can you clarify to me what you mean with "Why is self defined in Case 1 but not in Case 3?" ? You want to know why self is declared inside the function `number1` or why it is passed to the class `CheckProperty` from the class `TestSetter`?

Comment: My confusion is the following. In Case 1, Python seems to understand and passes self to the property. But in Case 3, Python does not understand that we're doing is equivalent to Case 1 and it should pass the self to the prop_check method of the CheckProperty object